# ConnectionException when running a Oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie, cascading, connectionexception

When trying to run a Oozie workflow with a Java action, I get the following error.

```
JA006: Call From sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15 to sandbox.hortonworks.com:10020 failed 
on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; 
For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

This is the workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="cascading-wordcount" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
<start to="wordcount_job"/>
<action name="wordcount_job">
    <java>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>jobTracker</name>
                <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com:8050</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <main-class>com.test.cascading.WordCount</main-class>
        <arg>/user/hue/oozie/test/cascading-in/rain.txt</arg>
        <arg>/user/hue/oozie/test/cascading-out</arg>
        <capture-output/>
    </java>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>
</action>
<kill name="kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

I can't even view the logs related to the job. When I try, it gives

```
Could not find job job_1453962161829_0005.
Job job_1453962161829_0005 could not be found: HTTPConnectionPool(host='sandbox.hortonworks.com', port=19888): Max retries exceeded with url: /ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/job_1453962161829_0005 (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

I can run the same jar used here using CLI with the command `yarn jar`. I'm a novice to these. I fear I might have done a stupid mistake.

**EDIT**

This is what I get when trying to view the logs through CLI as snies said.

```
impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15:8050
/app-logs/root/logs/application_1453962161829_0005 does not exist.
Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled.
```

Comment: Try to get the logs via yarn cli like this: `yarn logs -applicationId application_1453962161829_0005` just replace "job_" with "application_".

Comment: Also can you show the exact command you use, when you "try to run" the workflow?

Comment: @snies, please see the edit. Also, I don't understand what you mean by your second comment. By "try to run" I meant submitting it as a job

Comment: please detail how you submit the job (via hue, via cli, what steps)

Comment: I've created an oozie workflow  with a Java action using the hue interface. I've provided the path to the jar file, the main class and the program arguments for the Java action. I ran the workflow by submitting it.

Comment: The error message is rather clear: Oozie tries to connect to **Job History** service (replaced by **Timeline Server** nowadays) on port 10020 (cf. `/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml` under `mapreduce.jobhistory.address`) but that service is not running.